# Embed IPython shell within the pydev (IPython) console

Tags: pydev

When I do:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

the console shows a strange prompt and the shell is not working properly.
I know that pydev itself uses IPython but some other shell (like web2py interactive shell) also do that and it won't work.

In a console embedding IPython recursively many times works well.

Any idea to get it work?

Thanks,
Gergely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the console in PyDev is not a real tty replacement (which IPython expects to work properly).

So, ideally, if just for using IPython for dev you want to do, you can use the PyDev interactive interpreter: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html which is properly integrated in PyDev.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Fabio. Ok, it doesn't work with embed, but Pydev itself uses IPython if it's available, so there must be some workaround.

Comment: In PyDev, it actually creates a different process and does xml-rpc communication instead of putting things directly in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding another IPython shell within another IPython shell is now supported as of 3.0 - the I upstreamed patches for it last year.

Specifically you can do the following to your hearts content, from whatever IPython instance you are in, provided the default command shell works:

```
from IPython import embed; embed()
```